Take intermed or advanced series for phd application
I am an undergrad majoring in Math and want to apply for a PhD in Economics (maybe in theory and Econometrics). I have taken the intro series (intro micro and macro) already. Since I am about to graduate, I do not have many quotas for courses selection. If I can choose between taking the intermediate series (intermed micro, macro and metrics) or the advanced series (advanced micro, macro and metrics, intended for graduate students), which one is better?
In other words, if I have taken the advanced series, will that I haven't taken the intermed series become a disadvantage when it comes to PhD application? Or are both the intermed and advanced series essential and I should take both by giving up on some math courses?

Advanced absolutely. You will find the math straightforward if you are majoring in it.

The intermediate series will probably have a lot of definitions and more basic stuff. E.g., I imagine intermediate macro covers the IS/LM model, whereas advanced covers things like DSGE models.
If your goal is a PhD, the advanced is definitely more important. Being aware of the ideas of the intermediate courses would be useful though, so doing some self-study over the summer is probably a good idea.

Thanks! If I choose to take the advanced series, it is still necessary/worthy to give up on some math courses and take the intermed series?

Honestly, I wouldn't give up any math courses. If you intend to pursue a phd then you wil receive those treatments anyways. As Michael stated, the macro series would be more like IS/LM than what is currently prevailing in the macro literature.
This is intended to provide intuition before rigour (I think).
I did however find the intermediate micro class brought a lot of intuition to what we were doing that the more advanced micro class lacked. That being said, you can fill in these intuition gaps by reading the micro texts yourself and even having conversations with others about it.

tldr; math courses are incredibly valuable in a phd program. From someone who didn't do enough and had to self study in tandem with core micro/macro phd courses.

@Brennan I see. In that case, another way for me to take the intermed series is to do them in a summer school, but that takes a lot of money, so I am considering whether it is really worth it. If I have taken the advanced series, does whether I have taken the intermed series matters when it comes to PhD application?

I doubt it matters.
Math classes definitely matter. If nothing else they are important signals.

I agree, it wont matter. We love people with math backgrounds even if they haven't taken econ classes.

Thanks a lot Michael and @Brennan!

Consider accepting Michael's answer if you are satisfied :-)
